# How to solve error on SMTP connect when I try send email from php using phpMailer? POP/IMAP

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, imap, pop3

I am trying to use php to send an email from a php file to an outlook exchange account. The account is imap or pop not SMTP.

I keep getting an error SMTP connect() failed

```php
<?php
// Start with PHPMailer class
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 


// Base files 
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/POP3.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
// configure an SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'exchange2019.livemail.co.uk';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'email';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 995;

$mail->setFrom('email', 'Your Hotel');
$mail->addAddress('email', 'Me');
$mail->Subject = 'Thanks for choosing Our Hotel!';
// Set HTML 
$mail->isHTML(TRUE);
$mail->Body = '<html>Hi there, we are happy to <br>confirm your booking.</br> Please check the document in the attachment.</html>';
$mail->AltBody = 'Hi there, we are happy to confirm your booking. Please check the document in the attachment.';
// add attachment
$mail->addAttachment('//confirmations/yourbooking.pdf', 'yourbooking.pdf');
// send the message
if(!$mail->send()){
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: change host to `$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.livemail.co.uk';`

Comment: Add `$mail->SMTPDebug();` to show the actual error.

Comment: Does my answer work

Comment: @mikel Also double check your port as written mail setting port should be `587`.

Comment: @MohdAlomar, the port should be 465 when using SSL. And 587 when using tls

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana yes but I coping it from [here](https://smtpimap.email/livemail.co.uk-smtp-imap-email-settings.html) :)

Comment: @MohdAlomar, waiting for them to check my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use:

```
smtp.livemail.co.uk
```

instead of that.

And port `995` is for POP3. Try to use port `993`.

But, since you are trying to send mail, you will have to use port `465`

Or you can use port 587, and change the `SMTPSecure` to `tls`.

Answer (score 0):

```php
require_once("phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php");
require_once("phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tsl";
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
        $mail->Username   = '000@000';
        $mail->Password   = 'xxxxx';
        $mail_from        = "000@000";
        $subject          = "Hola";
        $body             = "email body";
        $mail_to          = "000@000";
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        try {
              $mail->Host= "smtp.office365.com";
              $mail->Port = "587";// ssl port :465, 
              $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
              $mail->AddAddress($mail_to, "000@000");
              $mail->SetFrom($mail_from,'000@000'); 
              $mail->Subject = $subject;
              $mail->MsgHTML($body);
              $mail->Send();
             $emailreturn = 200;
            } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
              $emailreturn = $e->errorMessage();             
            } catch (Exception $e) {
             $emailreturn = $e->getMessage();
            }
echo $emailreturn;
```

```
2021-02-10 18:08:02 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 MN2PR01CA0060.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed, 10 Feb 2021 18:08:01 +0000
2021-02-10 18:08:02 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2021-02-10 18:08:21 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2021-02-10 18:08:21 SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:
2021-02-10 18:08:21 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```